# How to reload Python module in IDLE?

Tags: python, module, reload, python-idle

I'm trying to understand how my workflow can work with Python and IDLE.

Suppose I write a function:

```
def hello():
    print 'hello!'
```

I save the file as `greetings.py`. Then in IDLE, I test the function:

```
>>> from greetings import *
>>> hello()
hello!
```

Then I alter the program, and want to try `hello()` again. So I `reload`:

```
>>> reload(greetings)
<module 'greetings' from '/path/to/file/greetings.py'>
```

Yet the change is not picked up. What am I doing wrong? How do I reload an altered module?

I've been reading a number of related questions on SO, but none of the answers have helped me.

Comment: `ctrl + f6` will restart your session as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to redo this line:

`>>> from greetings import *`

after you do

`>>> reload(greetings)`

The reason just reloading the module doesn't work is because the * actually imported everything inside the module, so you have to reload those individually.  If you did the following it would behave as you expect:

```
>>> import greetings
>>> greetings.hello()
hello!
```

*Make change to file*

```
>>> reload(greetings)
<module 'greetings' from 'greetings.py'>
>>> greetings.hello()
world!
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I get when I try your example (from a fresh Python interactive session):

```
>>> from greetings import *
>>> reload(greetings)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'greetings' is not defined
```

This indicates the source of the problem. When you use `from greetings import *`, the name `greetings` is not imported into the global namespace. Therefore, you cannot use `reload(greetings)` on it.

To fix this, try the following:

```
>>> import greetings
>>> greetings.hello()
hello
>>> reload(greetings)
<module 'greetings' from 'greetings.pyc'>
>>> greetings.hello()
hello world
```

Comment: I think in his example, he left out the fact that he did both import greetings and from greetings import *, so his example above works for him.  In that case, reloading greetings alone would not cause a call to hello() to be updated, even though a call to greetings.hello() would work correctly.

Comment: @Jacinda You are probably correct, I've tried a lot of things, and tried to distill the important behavior.

Comment: @FarmBoy It's an error I've had happen to me before.  I always get an "Oh, duh" feeling after I realize what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

IDLE has a menu pick to run the current file.  This will restart the shell by running your file first, reloading it.

Comment: Or you could just hit f5 in the file editor (idle) or just use ctrl-f6. Tons easier

Answer (score 1):

On windows, I use the shell->Restart shell or CTRL+F6 shortcut to restart and load the latest version of the modue